# android how to show foursqure login dialog without webview?

Tags: android, foursquare

i am using foursqure in my application,in which i have added option for foursqure login,and its working fine with webview.,now i want to show foursqure login dialog without webview..,is it possible to show login dialog of foursqure without webview,please help me.,thankyou.
here is my code

```
public class FoursqureMain  extends Activity {
public  Foursquare foursquare;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    foursquare = new Foursquare(

            "IMFHTE3P5TUSH1F1GOIBTRF52U3NAUFLJVUTYZLQY1XMPNCE"
            ,
            "UKP35K4J0GTMVY23OQBW5ZEFJDZZ1GCMLCQMDN3MCBVFVQ1X",
            "http://www.techvalens.net/://connect");

    foursquare.authorize(this, new FoursquareAuthenDialogListener());


}




class FoursquareAuthenDialogListener implements DialogListener {

    public FoursquareAuthenDialogListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        try {
            String aa = null;
            aa = foursquare.request("users/self");
            Log.d("Foursquare-Main", aa);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFoursquareError(FoursquareError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to authenticate a Foursquare user on Android is now to use [native auth](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2013/08/19/foursquare-native-auth-on-ios-and-android-developers-connect-your-users-more-quickly-than-ever/), bypassing the WebView altogether.